# Why won't unicodecsv write properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have the following Python code:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
import sys

with open("unicode_test.csv", "w+b") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, encoding="utf-8")
    writer.writerow([u'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c'])
```

This should create a CSV that says "こんにちは世界"; instead, it writes gibberish. Inspecting the end product with a hex editor shows similarities: EX YY ZZ gets converted to C3 AX C2 YY C2 ZZ, though I can't fathom how.

I am running Python 2.7.11 on Windows 10, and sys.stdout.encoding says "cp437" in the console.

Comment: Not really an answer, but when working with `unicode`, I've found it easier to port entire projects over to Python 3 than to untangle the various complicated ways (and their associated intermittent bugs) of dealing with unicode in Python 2.7. If you can, it's probably *way* worth it to use Python 3.

Comment: `\xe3\x81\x93` are the UTF-8-encoded bytes of `こ`.  Treating that as a Unicode string and encoding it as UTF-8 *again* is incorrect.  Treat it as a byte string and use the standard `csv` module, or use a correct Unicode string as @Sahan has shown.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try setting the source code encoding like this at the top of the source file:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

So, your entire solution should look like this:

```
# coding=utf-8
import unicodecsv as csv
import sys

with open("unicode_test.csv", "w+b") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, encoding="utf-8")
    writer.writerow([u'こんにちは世界'])
```

For further reading on using unicode character literals you can check the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) document

Let me know how it goes